# Tab gone after seconds shown but no errors (Honycomb)

Tags: android, class, android-tabhost

Got a funny thing.
I have app via several classes in the end shows tabhost screen build dynamic.
Tabs are dynamic as are the options below each tab.

On 2.2 this works perfect

But the new Honycomb the screen is shown, all tabs are there and options for the active tab are there but that's all no action possible and after some seconds everything disappears and (if it put it in) we are back at start ...

In my log I do not have any error regards to this. As soon as I let this run 2.2 it is running as wanted but if i try to run it in Honycomb I get this?

As I stated no errors in log but it seems I have a inactive screen after timeout or some going back.

It looks like in Honycomb I need something but so far I could not find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in my case. It turned out one of my Layout xml views had something fine if running in 2.2 but not ok in 3.0. Took some time to find this because I never had some error pointing to this at all. So, if one is having simular issues try to look at your layout xml to see if there is something in causing unwanted behavior inside your app.